# Doesn't load local html file at changing to third language (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I have 3 locally saved html files in 3 different languages in **lproj** folders in my xcode project. In every Localize.strings file there are keys for every html file name: 1)"history_file" = "history_en"; 2)"history_file" = "history_kz"; 3)"history_file" = "history_ru"; Also there are AboutCompanyViewController with table view witch contains 3 tableViewCells. At selecting cell, in AboutCompanyDetailVC should opens html file.

When I change languages it works only in two languages. I mean, if I change app language from English to Kazakh and backward, all works, but if I change the language to Russian html file doesn't open. And it doesn't matter to which languages are changed. It  opens html file if only two languages will changed, in changing to third language, it prints ("File reading error"). Is there an idea in what can be the problem?

in **AboutCompanyViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import InteractiveSideMenu

class AboutCompanyViewController: UIViewController, SideMenuItemContent, Storyboardable {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var cellImages = ["about_company-4.png", "about_company-2.png", "about_company-3.png"]
var cellLabels = ["history".localized, "production".localized, "partners".localized]
var webPages = ["history_file", "production_file", "partners_file"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "ABOUT COMPANY".localized
 }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func openMenu(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showSideMenu()
}

}
 extension AboutCompanyViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return min(cellImages.count, cellLabels.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AboutCompanyTableViewCell
    cell.label.text = cellLabels[indexPath.row]
    cell.cellImage?.image = UIImage(named: cellImages[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goTo" {
        let view = segue.destination as! AboutCompanyDetailVC
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        view.selected = self.webPages[indexPath.row]
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let height: CGFloat = 100.0
    return height
}

}
```

**AboutCompanyDetailVC:**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

 class AboutCompanyDetailVC: UIViewController,  UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

var selected: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "ABOUT COMPANY".localized
    loadHtmlFile()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 func loadHtmlFile() {
    let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]

    print("\(selected.localized) \(preferredLanguage)")
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: selected!.localized, withExtension: "html") {
        let request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    } else {
        print ("File reading error")
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked target of that html file which is not loading?

Comment: @sohanvanani, yes, I checked.